Twitter API 403 Forbidden
I created a Discord bot to do a subset of tasks for a gaming server.
Activision used to have a stats tracker, and it seems they have limited it down to their use. In any case, find you can enter your activision account into this X post, and it will return your combat record. I would like to do this straight from my Discord bot, however, I ran into this 403 forbidden error.
Error fetching original tweet: 403 Forbidden.

When authenticating requests to the Twitter API v2 endpoints, you must use keys and tokens from a Twitter developer App that is attached to a Project. You can create a project via the developer portal.
`import tweepy
import os
import re
import asyncio
from dotenv import load_dotenv
# Load environment variables from .env file
load_dotenv()

# Twitter API credentials from .env file
CONSUMER_KEY = os.getenv("TWITTER_API_KEY")
CONSUMER_SECRET = os.getenv("TWITTER_API_SECRET")
BEARER_TOKEN = os.getenv('BEARER_TOKEN')
ACCESS_TOKEN = os.getenv("TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN")
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = os.getenv("TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET")

# Set up Twitter API with tweepy for v2
client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=BEARER_TOKEN)
auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(
consumer_key=CONSUMER_KEY,
consumer_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET,
access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN,
access_token_secret=ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET
)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

# Helper function to extract tweet ID from URL
def extract_tweet_id(url):
tweet_id_match = re.search(r"status/(\d+)", url)
return tweet_id_match.group(1) if tweet_id_match else None

# Helper function to get the original tweet in the thread
def get_original_tweet_in_thread(tweet_id):
try:
    tweet = client.get_tweet(tweet_id, tweet_fields=["referenced_tweets"])
    while 'referenced_tweets' in tweet.data and tweet.data['referenced_tweets']:
        tweet_id = tweet.data['referenced_tweets'][0]['id']
        tweet = client.get_tweet(tweet_id, tweet_fields=["referenced_tweets"])
    return tweet.data['id']
 except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error fetching original tweet: {str(e)}")
    return tweet_id

# Function to send combat record request tweet
def send_combat_record_request(tweet_url, activision_name):
tweet_id = extract_tweet_id(tweet_url)
if not tweet_id:
    return None, "Invalid tweet URL. Please provide a valid tweet link."

original_tweet_id = get_original_tweet_in_thread(tweet_id)
status_message = f"{activision_name} #CODCombatRecord @CallofDuty"

try:
    response = api.update_status(
        status=status_message,
        in_reply_to_status_id=original_tweet_id,
        auto_populate_reply_metadata=True
    )
    return response.id, None
except tweepy.TweepyException as e:
    return None, f"Error posting tweet: {str(e)}"

# Function to check for combat record reply
def check_for_combat_record(tweet_id):
try:
    query = f'to:CallofDuty since_id:{tweet_id}'
    response = client.search_recent_tweets(query=query, tweet_fields=['text', 
'in_reply_to_user_id'])
    for tweet in response.data:
        if tweet.in_reply_to_user_id and tweet.in_reply_to_user_id == tweet_id:
            if "combat record" in tweet.text.lower():
                return tweet.text
    return None
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error fetching replies: {str(e)}")
    return None

# Asynchronous function to monitor replies
async def monitor_replies(ctx, tweet_id, activision_name):
while True:
    combat_record = check_for_combat_record(tweet_id)
    if combat_record:
        formatted_record = format_combat_record(combat_record)
        await ctx.send(f"Combat Record for {activision_name}:\n{formatted_record}")
        break
    await asyncio.sleep(60)

# Function to format the combat record
def format_combat_record(combat_record_text):
return combat_record_text`

